# Jquery returns .width() of element depending on how element was found

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
[$('*')[432]]
==>[<a id=​"mini_path_banner" href=​"/​daily-instant-wins-start">​Win over $1,000.00 Instantly​</a>​]

$('#mini_path_banner')
==>[<a id=​"mini_path_banner" href=​"/​daily-instant-wins-start">​Win over $1,000.00 Instantly​</a>​]

[$('*')[432]].width()
==>Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM5997:2

$('#mini_path_banner').width()
==>300
```

You can check it on this website: http://games.pch.com/. As I understand, two identical objects are returned by `[$('*')[432]]` and `$('#mini_path_banner')`. Then why performing the same method on them gives different results? And how to find width of element found by `$('*')[index]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[$('*')[432]].width()` should be `$('*').eq(432).width()`.

There are two things wrong with what you had:

1. `$('*')[432]` fetches a DOM object which doesn't have a `.width()` method.
2. `[$('*')[432]]` is a single element array with a DOM object in it which also doesn't have a `.width()` method.

Use `.eq(n)` to get an individual element into a new jQuery object (rather than just the DOM object by itself) so you can then call jQuery methods on it like `.width()`:

```
$('*').eq(432).width();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*')[432]
```

Its a DOM object, NOT a jQuery object

Two solutions:

```
$('*').eq(432).width()
//or
$($('*')[432]).width()
```